# How to force mysql edit command to use VIM color scheme?

Tags: mysql, vim, syntax-highlighting

When in mysql command prompt, the edit command which uses $EDITOR variable will result in a VIM environment without any color scheme.

Each time I create a new query, I must type ':set syntax=mysql'. This is because the temporary file name mysql create has no .sql extension. Here is an example of the name mysql can choose : /tmp/sql97H2iA.

**How can I get vim to set mysql syntax without my intervention?**

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec  9 2014 17:36:18)
Included patches: 1-488
Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the lines below to your `vimrc` will tell Vim to set the correct filetype of every buffer with a name starting with `sql` under `/tmp/`:

```
augroup sql
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNew,BufEnter /tmp/sql* setlocal filetype=sql
augroup END
```